# How to set Content-Type header in cordovaHTTP plugin requests

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use [cordovaHTTP](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) plugin and in my `POST` api calls, although I've set `Content-Type` header to `application/json` but I can see that content is sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format and no Content-Type header exist in headers of request.

usage sample:

```
cordovaHTTP.post("url/to/method",
 {
   "email": "ali@aliha.me"
 },
 {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 },
 function (result) {
   alert('success');
 },
 function (error) {
   alert('error');
 });
```

in the server api I see:

```
RAW BODY
email=ali%40aliha.me
```

**How** can I set `Content-Type` header?
*Note:* This approach of setting headers, works properly for other headers like `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin doesn't support `Content-Type` header in it's `post` method yet.
I used a [forked repository](https://github.com/brendonparker/cordova-HTTP) from dear [brendonparker](https://github.com/brendonparker) instead which has a `postJson` method for sending post requests with content-type of application/json.

Comment: I want to send apikey,userid,useragent,cookie,Connection,Accept-Encoding, Content-Type and Content-Length  to api . How should i construct my post request for forked repository ? I don't know which sending data be in header part of post request !Hope you help me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No mention in the plugin that it automatically encodes the request body as per the set "Content-Type". You would need to do that yourself.

Also, it seems there's no straight forward way to send data in the request body without specifying a key.value pair.

That's from the plugin documentation

```
/**
   * Write the values in the map as form data to the request body
   * <p>
   * The pairs specified will be URL-encoded in UTF-8 and sent with the
   * 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content-type
   *
   * @param values
   * @return this request
   * @throws HttpRequestException
   */
  public HttpRequest form(final Map<?, ?> values) throws HttpRequestException {
    return form(values, CHARSET_UTF8);
  }
```

you can encode your json string this way but you have to figure a way to send it in the request body

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({"email": "ali@aliha.me"});
```